# After upgrading Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10, I get a black screen with "grub rescue >"

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, grubrescue

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 then I restarted my computer as asked.

Now all I can see is `grub rescue >` on a black background.

What do I need to do?

Comment: try `boot-repair-disk`

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu won't boot and stuck at black screen](https://askubuntu.com/q/1265094/955434)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the upgrade completed successfully (except for Grub), use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to repair your Grub installation.