# Ubuntu won't boot and stuck at black screen

Tags: boot, grub2

I successfully dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 on windows 7. After a month, I removed my windows 7 and since then I started experiencing black screen at boot (without blinking cursor) which I somehow overcome with pressing the shift key or `esc` key, etc. My laptop use a
hybrid Intel/AMD graphic card which gave me problems on and off even while I was on windows.

Thinking a fresh install would solve the problem, I reinstalled Ubuntu (only) and encountered `error: unknown filesystem`. While trying to fix this, I might have messed somehow that I have the black screen everytime I try to boot, unable to even access the bios (and hence can't even live boot).

It would be great if someone could help me out on this. Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in these questions? https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem

Comment: @Zac Agner, now when I boot it doesn't even give the error, just the black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get back to the

`error: unknown filesystem`

`grub rescue >`

after clearing the CMOS following a guide similar to the explanations given here https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-clear-cmos-2624545

Following this guide [How to fix "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue) I eventually boot into my linux mint/ubuntu finally.

Hope someone with a similar problem finds it helpful!